# ExtendScript's UnitValue

Tags: adobe, extendscript

So I can't find, for the life of me, a clear breakdown of the components of ExtendScript's UnitValue object. Every source I found had something to do with Adobe, and didn't explain it. I'd really like to have a full reference on it, but if no one can find one, I need at least a few questions answered concerning it.
First, what are its constructors?
        *I've seen `UnitValue(10,'px')` which makes sense, but I've also seen `UnitValue(20,20)`*
Second, how can you convert from one unit to another?
Third, how can you find its value and its unit?
        *I think I've seen `uv.value` but nothing getting the units*
Lastly, as my tags indicate, this is for Adobe, of course, since I've never seen or heard of any other program that uses ExtendScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[UnitValue](http://estk.aenhancers.com/8%20-%20ExtendScript%20Tools%20and%20Features/specifying-measurement-values.html#unitvalue-object) is documented in the [Adobe JavaScript Tools Guide](http://estk.aenhancers.com/index.html).

In particular, you create an object with `v = new UnitValue(number, unit)`, where `unit` is a string value like `in` (inch), `mm` (millimeter), `pt` (point), `px` (pixel), etc.

To convert a UnitValue to an actual number, use the `as` method, e.g. `v.as("cm")` to convert `v` into centimeters.

Comment: Thanks! I looked around in the Photoshop documentation, but couldn't find anything but a vague description - from the book you found, I found it thoroughly defined on pages 230-232.

Comment: [Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) – which this one did.

Answer (score 5):

Well, no one else seemed to know, and I finally figured some of it out, so I guess I'll answer it myself:
[<This site>](http://jongware.mit.edu/Js/pc_UnitValue.html) was a little helpful as a  documentation, but I think Adobe functions slightly different from it.

UnitValue's main constructor is:

```
    UnitValue(numericalvalue,unit)
```

I've also seen an alternative that accepts one string:

```
    UnitValue("42 in")
```

For conversion, UnitValue comes with a handy `as` method which accepts the unit to convert to (as a string), and then returns its measurement in that unit, i.e.:

```
    UnitValue(5,'ft').as('in') === 60
```

(Note, according to the reference I found, I believe the `as` method should return the UnitValue instance after being converted to the unit indicated; Adobe's implementation, however, seems to instead merely return the value - therefore I'm use the type-equality operator above to show Adobe's method)
For getting the numerical value and measurement unit, the following two properties exist:

```
    UnitValue.value  // number: the numerical value
    UnitValue.type  // string: the unit of measurement
```

This is all I could find by my research. *If someone has a better answer, post it, and I may accept it.*

Answer (score 2):

What's really interesting to me is the `baseValue` property which allows us to change the frame of reference for the conversion. For instance:

```
var startUnit = UnitValue(500, "px");

startUnit.baseValue = UnitValue(1 / 72, "in"); // from what I can tell this is the default baseUnit value
$.writeln(v.as("in")); // returns 6.94444444444444 which is what 500px @ 72 dpi is as expressed in inches

startUnit.baseValue = UnitValue(1 / 300, "in"); // set to 300dpi
$.writeln(v.as("in")); // returns 1.66666666666667 which is what 500px @ 300 dpi is as expressed in inches
```

I think the default baseValue is always `UnitValue(1/72, "in")` even if the app.preferences.rulerUnits is set to any other type of measurement but I haven't really looked into it much

Comment: Good point, but no longer seems to be working: even with `var startUnit=UnitValue(100, "px"); startUnit.baseValue = UnitValue(1 / 300, "in");`, `startUnit.as('in')` becomes `1.3888` which is exactly `100/72`