# Photoshop Javascript API is set to millimetres, but uses pixels instead

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

## What am I doing

Using the javascript API of the Adobe Photoshop CC 2018 scripting engine:

```
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.MM;
app.preferences.typeUnits = TypeUnits.MM;
app.activeDocument.selection.select([
    [0,0],
    [0, UnitValue(150, "mm")],
    [UnitValue(150, "mm"), UnitValue(150, "mm")],
    [UnitValue(150, "mm"), 0]
]);
```

## What am I expecting to happen?

Photoshop creates a selection of 15×15 cm positioned at the top left.

## What is actually happening?

Photoshop creates a selection of 12.7×12.7 *pixels?* positioned I'm not even sure where exactly.

[image]

The document's size is 29.7×29.7 cm, so the selection is expected to take half of the artboard. Moreover, the "*marching ants*" aren't even set to the top left corner of the artboard.

I read most of [the referrence](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/scripting/photoshop_scriptref_js.pdf) plus tried to Google a lot, but the results I'm getting are misleading

**UPDATE** may not be in pixels after all because `UnitValue(150, 'mm').as('px')` outputs `425.196850393701` and not `12.7` which I believed to be the pixels value.

**UPDATE** tried setting the PPI to 300 to match the document's, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267019/extendscripts-unitvalue/51418594#51418594), but getting the same behaviour.

```
var startUnit=UnitValue(150, "mm");
startUnit.baseValue = UnitValue(1 / 300, "in");
```

Comment: I confirm the problem

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop likes to work with pixels, the use of inches, milimeters and centimeters is just for the convenience of us humans. Try:

```
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.MM;
var myMM = Number(myDocument.width);
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
var myPixels = Number(myDocument.width);

myDocument.selection.select([
    [0,0],
    [0, 150*myPixels/myMM],
    [150*myPixels/myMM, 150*myPixels/myMM],
    [150*myPixels/myMM, 0]
]);

app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.MM;
```

Where `myMM` is the width of the document in mm, and `myPixels` is the width of the document in pixels.

Comment: Does it? I find that while defining a path, the unit always is Points (1/72th inch) irrespective the setting of rulerUnits.